# can't find NDK-STACK.html in sdk\ndk-bundle folder

Tags: android, android-ndk

I also tried to run `ndk-stack.cmd`, but this did nothing. Does someone know how can I find it?  I need it to see about the `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xa2a23804 in tid 3819 (RenderThread)` error I get at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/633) in NDK. Once upon a time, all NDK docs were distributed in the same zip. Today you will find the guide online: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html.

Comment: hi thx @Alex, can you explain how to do this, it is still unclear to me after reading this guide